# Grails, extending with Rest

Tags: rest, grails

I have an existing domain, controller, view (auto generated for the latter) which works as expected in the browser.
It also works in curl if I have a URL of the .../user/show/1 or .../user/show ie I use an action which goes against REST principles.
So, I have added to the URLMappings file

```
 "/rest/user/$id?"(resource: "user")
```

which uses the auto generated controller.
The now works with curl and .../rest/user/1 but not .../rest/user - it runs the show method rather than the index method. But .../user does go to index and return a list.
Though the browser continues to work, I notice that the URLs are of the rest/user variety.

So I get the feeling I have not really understood this. Can I have two rules in the URLMappings file that point to the same place? According to the Grails 2.4.4 docs, a url with no id will use the index() method yet ..../rest/user is not - it goes to show().

What I have works but I am pretty sure I have not done it right.

Regards,
John

Answer (score 0):

I think grails creates Restful UserController for your domain. But if you already have got the UserController your own controller is used. You have to make it RESTFul. Take a look into [9.1.5.1 Extending the RestfulController super class](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/webServices.html#restfulControllers)

Also try to create urlmapping your controller manaully.

Comment: So the docs are not really create then? The choice is to access a domain via REST or via a browser if I want it to be automatic?

Comment: I did it with 2 different controllers. One for REST and an other one for Web. And I created mapping for each controller. If you already have got a UserController for Web try to rename it to UserWebController and create url mapping for it. I think grails tries to use UserController as RESTful but it is not RESTful or is it?
I think grails needs RESTful Controller to make your Domain available and if you already don't have one, grails will create one for you or use some default RESTful Controller. But you have already one UserController.

Comment: Take a look into Grails RestFulController. It is a template for an RestFulController. Ctrl + Shift + T and enter RestFulController in Editor.

Comment: I used the grails generate-restful-controller on my User domain earlier and that overwrote my existing UserController (I had backed up before I run it). Interestingly that did not extend RestfulController.

Comment: So have just realised that controller for User returns xml or json if I use curl with -H option. But though simply "localhost:8090/myapp/user" returns a list of users (good), "localhost:8090/myapp/user/1" returns a 404 error.

Comment: Is user with id = 1 exists? It is expected behavior in REST if it's not exists. You will get 404.
You can actually debug and stop in expected method to see if mapping works fine.